# Mark down editor for objective-c

Tags: objective-c, markdown

I need to implement a markdown editor in objective-c, that various buttons can be pressed after selecting text and then the markdown is applied to the selection.
So far I have easily gotten bold and italics, and more complicatedly, numbered lists, quote segments, code segments. I am guessing this will involve using regular expressions, so far I've avoided this but the code is quite ugly.

So are there any existing markdown libraries for objective-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not aware of an Objective-C library for Markdown. That said, since Objective-C is a superset of C, you could try a plain C Markdown library:

- [Discount](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/markdown/)
- [peg-markdown](https://github.com/jgm/peg-markdown)
- [libupskirt](http://git.instinctive.eu/cgit/libupskirt/tree/README)

Answer (score 0):

There's an Objective-C library named [markdownlive](https://github.com/rentzsch/markdownlive), built around [Discount](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/markdown/).